# Расчет расстояния

Tags: yandex-maps-api, api, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, карты

хотел подключить к сайту (дипломная работа) расчет стоимости перевозки груза по расстоянию. Пытался реализовать это через гугл карты и яндекс карты, но в обоих случаях нужно платить и платить не мало. Есть ли вариант сделать это без таких затрат?

Answer (score 1):

У Яндекса в песочнице есть пример расчета стоимости доставки:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator

На их странице с описанием JavaScript API (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/ ) говорится, что "Пользоваться API Яндекс.Карт можно бесплатно, если соблюдать условия" и далее - "Все данные должны отображаться на карте, размещённой на общедоступном сайте или в приложении. Сохранять или изменять данные нельзя...
Бесплатный API нельзя использовать для мониторинга транспорта и в закрытых системах. Общее число запросов к геокодеру, маршрутизатору и панорамам в сутки не должно превышать 25 тысяч". Полные условия есть на странице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/#index__conditions

Правильным будет написать техподдержке карт Яндекса, описать ваш сценарий использования их API и спросить о допустимости его бесплатного использования:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/feedback/troubleshooting-docpage/